# Not able to update maven dependencies in play 2 project

Tags: java, maven, playframework, dependencies, sbt

I have a maven 3 project 'turtle-beans'. I am deploying it on nexus repo from jenkins server. For example 'turtle-beans-6.6' is deployed on nexus.company.com in maven releases

I have another project in play 2.3 which uses this dependency. However when I mentioned a version no in build.sbt it downloads that version. But when I mention 'latest.integration' or 'latest.release', play/sbt do not download it from nexus repo. I tried everything ./activator reload, update commands. Didn't work for me.

Below are my files,
turtle-beans/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.turtle</groupId>
  <artifactId>turtle-beans</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>6.5</version>
  <name>turtle-beans</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Releases</name>
      <url>http://nexus.turtlemint.com/repository/maven-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <name>Snapshot</name>
      <url>http://nexus.turtlemint.com/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

 <!--  
 -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Build.sbt

```
//import de.johoop.findbugs4sbt.FindBugs._
//import de.johoop.findbugs4sbt._

name := """turtlemint"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
resolvers += "Nexus" at "http://nexus.turtlemint.com/repository/maven-public/"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  filters,
  "org.json" % "org.json" % "chargebee-1.0",
  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.4.3",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-elasticsearch" % "1.3.0.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-mongodb" % "1.9.2.RELEASE",
  "com.turtle" % "turtle-beans" % "latest-integration",
  "commons-beanutils" % "commons-beanutils" % "1.9.3"
)

transitiveClassifiers := Seq("sources")
```

What I want to achieve is, Play project should be able to pickup latest available version dynamically between locally installed jar and deployed on nexus repo. I don't want to update version numbers every time I deployed or install a new jar either on nexus repo or in local machine.

For example, if 6.5 is deployed on nexus repo and 6.5.1 is installed in local machine, play project should pickup 6.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivy's `latest.integration` or `latest.release` are "dynamic revisions" (which I'm using successfully with SBT and our ivy repository) that are not supported by maven.

This is because maven does not publish the needed "status" of the artifacts to the repository since it does not know about; ie. the pom.xml does not have this concept.

With maven you could use time-based snapshot versions instead.

Comment: Thanks will try this timestamp approach